# Allow my users to point their subdomains to my server with CNAME, without having to use add-on domain in cpanel

Tags: apache, cpanel, subdomain, cname

So I have a service that allows my user to map their own subdomains to my server. For example

http://sub.userdomain.com will map to http://sub.mydomain.com

Now I know that the user must add a CNAME record that points to my subdomain, but using Apache & Cpanel, now I have to add an add-on domain for this connection to work.

Is there a workaround so that I don't have to set up this add-on domain for the connection to automatically connect? (Basically so that my user can point their CNAME to my subdomain and it then automagically works without me having to do manual input).

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

No, You need to add addon domain on your server so that cPanel will create entry in apache configuration to work that domain.